# Use "Self enrolment" in "Add a new course"

Tags: php, moodle

Im new for PHP and Moodle..., I want set **"Max enrolled users"** in the page **"Add a new course"**.

In this moment i did this code in archive(**moodle\course\edit_form.php**):

```
    $mform->addElement('text', 'customint3', get_string('maxenrolled', 'enrol_self'));

    $mform->addHelpButton('customint3', 'maxenrolled', 'enrol_self');

    $mform->setType('customint3', PARAM_INT);
```

but i know miss something for use **Self Enrolment** in this page... like active the table "enrol_self"...

For use "Self Enrolment" , first need to get "**CourseID**". Because in the page of "Self Enrolment" need a **foreign key** for updating the format of a course.

So... how can I do in the code "**edit_form.php**" for creating a course and updating Enrolment Self(maxenrolled) immediately after click the button?? Have function of moodle for easy edit it??

Need your advice please!! And thanks!!

Comment: You should not write anything in the Moodle core files, like edit_form.php. If you need to add custom code, you'd better create a custom course format (https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Course_formats#Creating_a_New_Format). Otherwise, you will have problems at every Moodle update.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default for max enrolled in the plugin settings. Go to site admin -> plugins -> enrolment -> self enrolment

or go directly to yoursite.com/admin/settings.php?section=enrolsettingsself

If you want to use a different value each time, then in /enrol/self/edit.php look for this code (this is the code in Moodle 2.5 it might be slightly different in other versions):

```
} else {
    require_capability('moodle/course:enrolconfig', $context);
    // No instance yet, we have to add new instance.
    navigation_node::override_active_url(new moodle_url('/enrol/instances.php', array('id'=>$course->id)));

    $instance = (object)$plugin->get_instance_defaults();
    $instance->id       = null;
    $instance->courseid = $course->id;
    $instance->status   = ENROL_INSTANCE_ENABLED; // Do not use default for automatically created instances here.
}
```

and insert this line

```
$instance->courseid = $course->id;
$instance->customint3 = $yourdefault; // Your new default.
$instance->status   = ENROL_INSTANCE_ENABLED;
```

Comment: Hi Sir! Thanks for replied to me. I have a dude... Could I use a "Global Variable" in edit_form.php: "$mform->addElement('text', 'customint3', get_string('maxenrolled', 'enrol_self'));"           and pass variable to the the line "$instance->customint3 = $yourdefault;"?? for set a default value in this line.